# Jack and Chrissy reference in Friends by Chandler

Tags: dialogue, friends

In the *Friends* episode **The one with two parties**, while Mr. and Mrs. Green both came to the party and Monica was panicking why did Chandler say:

> what would Jack and Chrissy do?

**Who were Jack and Chrissy?**

Here is the full context:

> **Mrs. Green**: Oh well thank you. Such a gentleman. Thank you. (Chandler
>   takes the hot pink coat and grimaces at it) Ahh, it all looks so nice,
>   so festive, all the balloons... (Chandler, remembering that Joey and
>   Mr. Green are in the bedroom, throws her coat in a cupboard) The
>   funniest thing happened to me on the way here. I was...(Joey peeks
>   out)
>
> **Phoebe**: (cutting Mrs. Greene off) Ha-ha, that's great, ha-ha. I can't
>   wait to hear the rest of it, ya know, but I really have to go to the
>   bathroom so... Hey, come with me. Yeah, yeah, it'll be like we're gal
>   pals, ya know, like at a restaurant Oh, it'll be fun, c'mon. (They go
>   in the bathroom)
>
> **Monica**: Oh my God, oh my God, oh my God.
>
> **Chandler**: *Ok, think, what would Jack and Chrissy do?*

Comment: Aaaand... now I feel old

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's an homage to [Three's Company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three%27s_Company):

[image]

[image]

Chrissy Snow (on the right) and Jack Tripper (in the middle) are two characters from the show.

Note: This isn't the first reference to *Three's Company* in the show. In Episode 1.02 (*[The One with the Sonogram at the End](http://www.friends-tv.org/zz102.html)*), while watching TV with Phoebe, Chandler does sarcastically remark:

> **Chandler**: Oh--I think this is the episode of "Three's Company" where
>   there's some kind of misunderstanding.
>   **Phoebe**: Then I've already seen
>   this.

Comment: The joke of the Three's Company reference in EP 1.02 is that EVERY episode was **some kind of misunderstanding**.

Answer (score 8):

Jack and Chrissy were two characters in the 70's/80's hit SitCom [Three's Company](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0075596/), played by John Ritter and Suzanne Sommers respectively.  The characters were often finding themselves in uncomfortable or compromising situations.